# If two consecutive columns are equal and adjacent column has variations find those entries

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, powerquery

For Excel, I want to compare all consecutive cells in a column with the values in adjacent column. If there is a variation for same consecutive cells having same values, I want to copy the **entire row** to a new tab called "incorrect coding error"

Problem snip:

[image]

So in the sample Image, you can see that there are some  dupicate entries hash Value header, and in the adjacent cell having header "Coding" there are coding value for Hash Value. I have colour coded for ease of identification.

For the yellow hilighted and Blue highlighted hash values the "coding" column are same and for Orange/Brown/Grey has values, the codings are different (these cells also highlighted in Red for ease identification)

For each hash value where codings are different, I would like to have those rows populated in a new tab by what ever name (say "Coding Error").

[image: Solution Image]

Another related issue is that the header "Hash" and "Coding" are not same for all data, so I would really appreciate if I could manually input these headers for any variations - I mean option to recognise variations within VBA.

Futher, as discuused, **entire ROWS** needs to be copied to the new tab as you can see there are other headers like control no and file name I would like to preserve.
I did not tried VBA new to this

Comment: OK, so what have you tried? What specific problem did you run into getting your idea to work?

Comment: As I have just said to another poster - does this have to be in VBA. This is the sort of task I use Power Query for

Comment: @CHill60, PowerQuery may work fine in case there are only 2 column, I am dealing with multiple columns so a revist to my orininal request which I have revised today is really appreciated.

Comment: @AjitDohaliya Power Query works fine with multiple columns too. As I said, I do this sort of task on a regular basis and I use Power Query for it.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved and perhaps upvote it with arrow

Answer (score 2):

Bring your data into powerquery using data .. from table/range [x] headers

[image]

Paste this code into home...advanced editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], //preserve your own first row if different from this sample first row
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Hash Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"data", each _, type table }}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Count] <> 1),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"data"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "data", {"Hash Value", "Coding"}, {"Hash Value", "CodingError"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

file.. close and load... back into excel as a Table. You can then right-click refresh the table as source change, or refresh it using VBA

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, objDic, objDic2, sKey As String, sKey2 As String
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 2)
    ' Load header
    arrRes(1, 1) = arrData(1, 1)
    arrRes(1, 2) = arrData(1, 2)
    j = 1
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        ' Check hash value
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            If Not objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2) Then
                ' Check hash value + coding
                sKey2 = arrData(i, 1) & objDic(sKey)
                If Not objDic2.exists(sKey2) Then
                    j = j + 1
                    arrRes(j, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
                    arrRes(j, 2) = objDic(sKey)
                    objDic2(sKey2) = ""
                End If
                sKey2 = arrData(i, 1) & arrData(i, 2)
                If Not objDic2.exists(sKey2) Then
                    j = j + 1
                    arrRes(j, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
                    arrRes(j, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
                    objDic2(sKey2) = ""
                End If
            End If
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("D:E").Clear
    Range("D1").Resize(j, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[image]

Comment: This is awesome and it almost worked, but my apologoes for not being clear, I would like to have all the entries of A21D131 in the above example (so it will have the First two rows of Non Responsive (even though duplicative within Coding column), as well as 3rd and 4th Entry. Also, if we could populate the entire rows having these conflicts to a new tab - that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Further, just realised (and apologies for peacemeal updates), the actual data contains other columns as well with data, so  instead if copying the Hash and Coding values, I need to copy the rows to the new tab. The naming convention of Hash and Coding are also not same, so if there is added functionality to add search for specific headers such as "Hash", that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `have all the entries of A21D131` the output will be exactly same as the source table. For the the 2nd comment, it is doable. I would suggest to create a post/question and share data layout and expected result.

Comment: many thanks for your guidance, I have edited my original post ready for your perusal.

Comment: could you please revist the original port, now edit and share your guidance?

Comment: If the code solves your original question, pls accepte it as answer and open a new question. We would like to help you on it. You can rollback your post editing history. [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: My apologies, I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77610453/18349732

Answer (score 1):

you could use nested dictionaries
be sure to have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library referenced in your VBA IDE (Tools -> References, select and tick that entry and click OK)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        
        Dim cel As Range ' read and store hashes and their corresponding coding values
            For Each cel In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                If Not dict.Exists(cel.Value2) Then
                    dict.Add cel.Value2, New Scripting.Dictionary
                End If
                
                    Dim subDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
                        Set subDict = dict(cel.Value2)
                        
                            If Not subDict.Exists(cel.Offset(, 1).Value2) Then
                                subDict.Add cel.Offset(, 1).Value2, 1
                            End If
            Next

                Dim iKey As Long ' remove hashes with only one entry from the dictionary
                    For iKey = dict.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                        Dim key As Variant
                            key = dict.Keys(iKey)
                                If dict(key).Count = 1 Then
                                    dict.Remove key
                                End If
                    Next
                    
                        If dict.Count > 0 Then ' if any hashes with more than one coding value survives
                            With Range("D1") ' write them 
                                .Resize(, 2).Value = .Offset(, -3).Resize(, 2).Value
                                For Each key In dict
                                    With Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)
                                            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(dict(key).Count).Value = key
                                            .Offset(1, 1).Resize(dict(key).Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict(key).Keys)
                                    End With
                                Next
                            End With
                        End If
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please revisit my original post, now revised and explained better for the final results. Thanks in advance..